# In python list comprehension can we look at previous values created during execution

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a dictionary and as I am creating it during list comprehension can I access the previous values created?

Example:

```
h = {i:1+h[i-1] for i in range(1,100))}
```

Comment: No. And if you need that, a list comprehension is not the right tool as, per definition, it means the element are handled independently. Maybe have a look at itertools functions such as [`accumulate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate).

Comment: You call it "list comprehension" but you build dictionary. Unfortunately you cannot use it so. Since the variable h will point to the new dict object only when it has been created, you cannot access it before. You can do it with a for loop.

Comment: What Python version?

Comment: @quantummind they are stil called list comprehension. Such operations are all termed under that I guess. My python version is 3.4.4

Comment: It's a dict comprehension. A list comprehension applies only to building lists.  I'd imagine a more general term of comprehension would be applicable.

Comment: @277roshan No, it is called a dictionary comprehension. See for example, the [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/).

Comment: @277roshan you'd have to give up on the comprehension and generate it in a manual loop.

Comment: @277roshan "dict comprehension" or "dictionary comprehension" are used as well. I understand your point but in that case in subject I would put "for dictionary" to be more precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit: I read `i:i + h[i-1]` instead of `i:1 + h[i-1]`.** The latter is always equal to `i:i` except in the first case, when it is `1+None`

This does what you want in a dictionary comprehension. Requires Python 3.2 or higher:

```
from itertools import accumulate 
h = {i:v for i,v in enumerate(accumulate(range(100)))}
```

otherwise use this

```
def accumulate(r):
    next_value = 0
    for i in r:
        next_value = next_value + i
        yield next_value
```

Comment: Well, really the first case is undefined. `None` is reasonable, but it could be anything.